# Laravel - Cargar archivo en input file

Tags: laravel, archivo, entrada

Tengo una tabla que guarda imagenes, pero el problema es que al momento de entrar a modificar, tambien necesito cargar esa imagen en el `input file`

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file {{ $errors->has('archivo') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="archivo[]">
```

> ¿como puedo asignarle el archivo al input?

```
@foreach($materiales as $material)
   ... 
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes por razones de seguridad, imagínate:

```
<form name="foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="c:/passwords.txt">
</form>
<script>document.foo.submit();</script>
```

No quieres que las páginas que visites hagan esto por ti, ¿o sí? :)

Lo que yo haría sería que pondría algo como: "Archivo Actual: ejemplo.jpg", (si el archivo es una imagen pues desplegaría la imagen actual en thumbnail) y en el input pondría una leyenda que diga, "sube un archivo nuevo para actualizarlo", hay muchas formas de hacerlo user friendly pero ya depende de tu imaginación y tu diseño.

En tu controlador verificarías que el archivo exista:

```
//verificar que haya un archivo subido por el usuario
if($request->hasFile('archivo')){
   //teniendo en cuenta que ya tienes tu modelo cargado:
   if($modelo->imagen){ //si es un registro que ya tiene una imagen cargada
      if(Storage::disk('nombre_de_tu_disco')->exists($modelo->imagen)){ // Comprobar que exista el archivo
         Storage::disk('nombre_de_tu_disco')->delete($modelo->imagen) //Eliminar el archivo viejo
      }
   }

   //subir el archivo nuevo

   $request->archivo->storeAs('', 'ejemplo.jpg', 'nombre_de_tu_disco'); //subir archivo nuevo
   $modelo->imagen = 'ejemplo.jpg'; //guardar nombre de nuevo archivo en el modelo
   $modelo->save();
}
```

Hay varias formas de borrar archivos y guardarlos, pero ya depende de ti, la lógica que ocuparías, sería una semejante a la que te pongo.

Comment: ¿Recomendación?

Comment: Claro, editaré mi respuesta con mi recomendación.

Comment: Listo, ya edité mi respuesta :)