# crud Laravel con archivos

Tags: php, laravel, archivo, crud

Hice un CRUD en Laravel, pero cuando intento editar un registro, el input file aparece vacío.
Uno de mis archivos es el siguiente

Controller.php

```
public function machine(Request $request)
    {
        $work_desc=$request->file('work_desc')->store('manual','public');

}
 public function update(Request $request, $Machine_Id)
    {
              $machine->qr_code_machine = $data['qr_code_machine'];
              $machine->save();
    }
```

blade.php

```
    <input type="file" name="qr_code_machine"
    value="{{asset('storage').'/'.$machine->getQrCodeMachine()}}"/>
```

El error es que cuando hago click en editar, me llena todos los campos menos el input file

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel - Cargar archivo en input file](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240297/laravel-cargar-archivo-en-input-file)

Comment: nope...........

Comment: Por motivos de seguridad, no puedes asignar valor por defecto a _input tipo file_. El manejo de archivos existentes se debe realizar de forma interna, verificando que el registro tiene archivo o no, para conservar el actual o remplazar si es que se subió uno nuevo.

Comment: perfecto, y como hago eso?